# Can I use Infopath code behind in SharePoint online?

Tags: infopath, 2013

I'm evaluating using SharePoint online for a new project, but I can't find a definite answer to whether I'm able to use InfoPath 2013 code behind (e.g. custom code in an InfoPath form) in SharePoint online?

I'd like to build some extensive InfoPath forms but I really need to be able to use custom code. Can anyone confirm whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Infopath with code-behind in Sharepoint Online (Office 365) since June 2012 (now is 2013, since January).

Commenting [another answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/56620/8319) with reference to:

- "Using code with InfoPath Services in SharePoint Online will not be supported by Office 365 moderators and this type of implementation may not be possible **if it is required it be published to the Central Admin site**.  The article below will detail how to configure InfoPath Forums Services in SharePoint Online.  Let us know if you have further questions"
  http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/153/p/59614/220124.aspx

Once more, it is written under condition of:

- **"if it is required it be published to the Central Admin site"**

This tells no more than about misconfiguration, misuse and unsupported usage of Sharepoint Online (Office 365). That is, in Sharepoint Online it is impossible to access Central Administration, and respectively create or deploy any solutions requiring deployment or configuration through Central Administration page (aka Administrator Approved Infoapth form templates or features unsupported by sandboxed apps, etc.)

Basically, I never had any problems with code behind. One should just follow some obvious restrictions which are basically avoiding to access something outide of Sharepoint Online site, i.e. to stick with using built-in features (web services) and with those deployed to SPO site.

Though, this is a theory but in practice there is an amount of maverick bugs especially after Sharepoint Online migration from 2010 to 2013:

- [with 3d-party tools engagement](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/24433/85710.aspx)

There is also a webpage with officially shared (II mean by that that there are not shared and/or "approved" by Microsoft) bugs being processed by Microsoft team:

- [Issues you may encounter after you receive the latest SharePoint Online service update in Office 365](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2789555)

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. SPO decided to bless our company with an early and bug-ridden upgrade to 2013 that caused any Infopath form with just about any code-behind (I can't recall if I was able to do something extrememly basic and useless on its own, like read a field, but anything else caused the form to break or require it to be downloaded locally) to become inoperable. After a month of being on the phone with them pretty much daily while our site was basically crippled they finally told us it that code-behind on an Infopath form will not be useable in Sharepoint Online 2013. This was told to us the end of November, 2012. Good-bye Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "it depends". If it needs to be send to Central Admin, then no. If not, it may be possible.

"Using code with InfoPath Services in SharePoint Online will not be supported by Office 365 moderators and this type of implementation may not be possible if it is required it be published to the Central Admin site.  The article below will detail how to configure InfoPath Forums Services in SharePoint Online.  Let us know if you have further questions."

http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/153/p/59614/220124.aspx