# how to create form on infopath for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

I'm very new to share point. I want to create a train ticket booking form, which will allow requester to enter their no. of tickets, journey date, number of travelers and then a submit button , once they press the submit, our general office should get a notification that some one has requested to book a ticket . How can i achieve that? any help will be very helpful,

I will use info path to create form.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to walk you through the (
[Alternative options for InfoPath on SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/201306/alternative-options-for-infopath-on-sharepoint-online)).

Also, I Found some useful links on how to create infopath forms in SharePoint:

1. [Customize a SharePoint list form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-c1f9283d-f704-4bbe-a8aa-827425ab31ae).
2. [Creating a SharePoint form with infopath designer](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1670194).
3. [How to create and publish infopath form in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-create-and-publish-InfoPath-in-SharePoint-2013).

And for sending notifications, you can create a workflow on item creation in SharePoint list. Below are some useful links for that:

1. [Creating a workflow with SharePoint designer that sends an email](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/sharepoint-designer-2013-custom-workflows/creating-a-workflow-with-sharepoint-designer-that-sends-an-email).
2. [Send email in a workflow](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/send-e-mail-in-a-workflow-11d5f9dd-955f-412c-b70f-cde4214204f4#bm1).

Comment: Thank you @Ganesh bhai. Today I’m on leave, Monday I will try to create the form as per the useful link you have provided. I will let you know how it goes. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: as per our specifications they also want to send the detail of the filled form along with the content to our general office email once the user click submit. I have seen the workflow call send email , but couldn’t send the detail of the form it just send notification that a form has been submitted.Any help on this will be more than awesome

Comment: If you want to send the item details in email then easy way is to use OOTB [alerts](https://www.collaboris.com/configure-alerts-sharepoint-2016/) functionality in sharepoint. Or if you are using workflow then you need to hard code table in email body and print each field from `Current Item`.

Comment: It all worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: Welcome. Please accept the answer so that others can benefit from accepted answer.